# How can you read from standard input in Unison?

Tags: unison-lang

How can you read `Text` from standard input in Unison?

Answer (score 1):

You can read `Text` with [IO.console.readLine](https://share.unison-lang.org/@unison/code/latest/namespaces/public/base/latest/IO/console/;/terms/readLine); from the doc example:

```
use Text ++
printLine "Important question: what's your favorite type of pie?"
printLine "> "
pie = !getLine
printLine (pie ++ "!? No way, me too!!! ")
```

And as you can see in the example, you can print a line of `Text` with `IO.console.printLine`.

Comment: also see: https://share.unison-lang.org/@unison/code/latest/namespaces/public/base/latest/;/terms/io/stdIn

Comment: stdIn moved to https://share.unison-lang.org/@unison/code/latest/namespaces/public/base/latest/;/terms/IO/Handle/stdIn